# Getting rid of dupes in path-like environment variable set in ~/.profile

Tags: bash

*[Ubuntu 19.10 with `gdm`]*

Here are the contents of my `$HOME/.profile`:

```
# ~/.profile: executed by the command interpreter for login shells.
# This file is not read by bash(1), if ~/.bash_profile or ~/.bash_login
# exists.
# see /usr/share/doc/bash/examples/startup-files for examples.
# the files are located in the bash-doc package.

# the default umask is set in /etc/profile; for setting the umask
# for ssh logins, install and configure the libpam-umask package.
#umask 022

# if running bash
if [ -n "$BASH_VERSION" ]; then
    # include .bashrc if it exists
    if [ -f "$HOME/.bashrc" ]; then
    . "$HOME/.bashrc"
    fi
fi

# set PATH so it includes user's private bin if it exists
if [ -d "$HOME/bin" ] ; then
    PATH="$HOME/bin:$PATH"
fi

# set PATH so it includes user's private bin if it exists
if [ -d "$HOME/.local/bin" ] ; then
    PATH="$HOME/.local/bin:$PATH"
fi

XDG_DATA_DIRS=$HOME/PRATAP/:$XDG_DATA_DIRS
```

I have added the last line in above file., that is `XDG_DATA_DIRS=$HOME/PRATAP/:$XDG_DATA_DIRS`

when I rebooted..

```
$ env | grep XDG_DATA_DIRS
XDG_DATA_DIRS=/home/admin/PRATAP/:/usr/share/ubuntu:/usr/local/share/:/usr/share/:/var/lib/snapd/desktop
$
```

Log out and login..

```
$ env | grep XDG_DATA_DIRS
XDG_DATA_DIRS=/home/admin/PRATAP/:/home/admin/PRATAP/:/usr/share/ubuntu:/usr/local/share/:/usr/share/:/var/lib/snapd/desktop
```

Again Log out and login..

```
$ env | grep XDG_DATA_DIRS
XDG_DATA_DIRS=/home/admin/PRATAP/:/home/admin/PRATAP/:/home/admin/PRATAP/:/usr/share/ubuntu:/usr/local/share/:/usr/share/:/var/lib/snapd/desktop
```

the path I have added is repeating., that is `$HOME/PRATAP/`.

Is there a way to stop this repeating?

Comment: It looks like you're never leaving your login shell session when logging out.  How exactly are you "logging out"?

Comment: @Kusalananda Thanks for your response.. The GUI way.. Click User.. Choose Logout

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to clean up your XDG_DATA_DIRS variable.  The fact you experience the dupes in your env-var only upon logout/in is consistent both with what you describe, with the content of your .profile file and with the general solution below

First define the executable script `pathclean` (adapted from @Gilles' June 17, 2012 post # 40749 on Stackexchange, whose url I could not find for some reason):

```
$ cat pathclean
#!/usr/bin/bash
# Cleans up PATH variable 
# Script accepts exactly 2 arguments
dedup_path() {
    if [ -n "$1" ]; then # TRUE if length of string is !=0
            OLPATH=${1}:; NUPATH=""
        while [ -n "$OLPATH" ]; do  
            x=${OLPATH%%:*}   # keep 1st entry in string $OLPATH
            case $NUPATH: in
                *:"$x":*) ;;                    # already there
                *) NUPATH=$NUPATH:$x ;; # not there yet
            esac
            OLPATH=${OLPATH#*:} # remove 1st entry in $OLPATH
        done
        NUPATH=${NUPATH#:}
        unset OLPATH x
    fi
    echo "$NUPATH"
}

echo $( sed -e 's/::/:/g' -e 's/:$//' <(dedup_path "${2}") )
exit 0
```

Just put `pathclean` where you usually keep your scripts. That could be in either `$HOME/.local/share/` or `/opt/bin/` . In your case, `$HOME/.local/share/`  might be the best location. Then make it executable with `$ chmod +x $HOME/.local/share/pathclean`.

Finally don't forget to append your `$HOME/.profile`  with the line:

```
  XDG_DATA_DIRS=$($HOME/.local/share/pathclean XDG_DATA_DIRS "$XDG_DATA_DIRS").
```

It is important that the line above be placed **at the end** of your `$HOME/.profile`.

The script is run automatically from your $HOME/.profile, which is sourced once upon GUI-login by your login manager.

This should keep dupes at bay for you. You can also apply that dupe-cleanup to your PATH env-var without problem.

Comment: do I need to add this script to autostart? I will try in some time.. But seems bit of overkill bcoz the repeating problem I mentioned in question is only for Logout n back in.. Reboot makes it one time only..

Comment: Hi.. I use Ubuntu 19.10 which is there since from the question origin with out any edits.. Login manager is gdm3 which is derived from Ubuntu 19.10 with out any customizations...  I think `pathscreen` script needS to be kept somewhere and I have to make it run at every login rite?

Comment: Will try now and I will respond.. Thank you.

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/uagfU.png. Its done. Nice Script!!!